# how to make View Pager for Image Slideshow like Blackberry 10 Home Screen

Tags: slideshow, qml, blackberry-10, cascade, viewpagerindicator

I need some help to make view pager for image slideshow, just like Blackberry Home Screen. You know there's no component for pager in QML. I've searching alternative way and i found nothing. Some people give me concept to make this, but i don't know how to implement it, i'm still need example code to make it, can anybody help me please

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this](http://www.clearbridgemobile.com/2012/11/11/using-a-horizontal-listview-to-display-images/)?

Where you create a horizontal listview and fill it with images?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i've solved my problem with this https://github.com/Macadamian/BB10/tree/master/CarouselDemo